# Twitter Widget disappears

Tags: twitter, widget

I have embedded a twitter widget on my CMS it appears then disappears.

I don't know why though, is it the code?

I've edited all I know and it's still doing this.

Hers is the code:

[code]

```
<style type="text/css">
.twtr-hd {
display:none;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.twtr-ft div {
display:none;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px;
}
</style>

<script charset="utf-8" src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>
<script>
new TWTR.Widget({
  version: 2,
  type: 'profile',
  rpp: 1,
  interval: 30000,
  width: 533,
  height: 50,
  theme: {
    shell: {
      background: '#ffffff',
      color: '#ffffff'
    },
    tweets: {
      background: '#ffffff',
      color: '#000000',
      links: '#0098DB'
    }
  },
  features: {
    scrollbar: false,
    loop: false,
    live: true,
    hashtags: true,
    timestamp: true,
    avatars: true,
    behavior: 'all'
  }
}).render().setUser('twitteraccount').start();
 $('#twitterSearch').liveTwitter('twitteraccount', {limit: 1, rate: 50000}); 
</script>
```

[/code]

Comment: Try the new widget provided by Twitter http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887045/twitter-widget-disapears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem. Read something about rate limiting prevents from making a request to the API more than 150 times per hour. However I experience this problem much earlier than that.
Very annoying when trying to make custom css-rules when you cannot see the results.

EDIT: I figured it was because I sit on a public IP in my office and other computers here makes requests as well.